# Closing calender when a date is selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, calendar

I am creating a new calendar control. I have set the selected date as the button text. I need to close my calendar when a date is selected.

```
<Window x:Class="DemoApp2.Views.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
     <Window.Resources>
     </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
      <ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Content="{Binding SelectedDate, ElementName=CalendarControl}" Background="Red" Margin="50,103,55,130">
      </ToggleButton>
      <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Scroll" PlacementRectangle="50,53,50,50">
         <Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
         </Calendar>
       </Popup>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

I prefer xaml code. Awaiting your valuable help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Blend Behaviors` for your pure XAML approach.

Download [Blend 3 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22829) , [Blend 4 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=10801).

> xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
>   xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Content="{Binding SelectedDate, ElementName=CalendarControl}" Background="Red" Margin="50,103,55,130"/>

<Popup x:Name="Popup1" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn, Mode=TwoWay}" StaysOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Scroll" PlacementRectangle="50,53,50,50">
    <Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl"               
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDatesChanged">
                <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="btn" PropertyName="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Calendar>
</Popup>
```

Comment: I am using .net framework 4.5. I am unable to install System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. Do we have any version that supports in 4.5?

Comment: Please see updated code, I have posted Blend SDK 4 download link.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is working fine after installing System.Windows.Interactivity.dll from Package Manager Console.